# Can I use any other column name than id in my xamarin forms app?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

As the title suggest, I was wondering if it was possible to use any other column name for the index than `id`?

The documentation for creating a Mobile Backend in Azure and Xamarin Forms app stipulates that the index column must be `id` all lower case for the API to return data.  What if your index column is called something else, for example `idx_index`.

My issue is that my database already exists and there are a lot of tables.  I'd like to avoid having to rename the index columns in the database if I can.

Is there anything I can do that would help me avoid this problem or does it look like I'll need to rename my columns to `id`?

Comment: You're not clear (complete) about the dataflow. This is often corrected with a `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]` attribute but it's unclear if that's applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my database already existed all the column naming was set.  To get around this problem when it came to Azure and it's expectation of a column called `id` I simply cast the column names in some custom views which were specific to my mobile app.  For example:

```
SELECT index_idx as id,
       name,
       location
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

No - you cannot use any other name other than id.  This is in-built into the SDK and you would need to alter both the server and client SDKs (and compile new ones) to support something else.  This is a non-trivial update.